# Wordpress Page Name with Custom Post Type slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am developing a Wordpress Theme where I would like users to create Guides onto the website directly.

So I have my custom post type called "Guides", I have been able to create a page called "Guides" where all the guides are listed.
To do so, I had to put this args on the "Register_Post_Type"

```
'has_archive'           => false,
```

Now I would like to create a page called "Create" under "Guides" parent, where user would be able to create guides from there, but I am not able to make this page work, since then I go to "mywebsite.com/guides/create", it search for a "Guides" called "create". So I do I do to exclude "Create" page from the post type, so I would be able to head to this page.

Comment: Why are you making the **Create Page** child of **Guides** Page ? You can use the **Guide Page** for the listing while **Create Page** can be separately used to create new posts.

Comment: Don't try and hack the permalink structure.  You won't win.  Just make the "create" page a top-level page - you can still easily list it as a "child" in your **menus**, with it *actually* being a child.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: Ok so I shouldn't make a child page with it ?

Cause I wanted to have the create page link like this
"mywebsite.com/guides/create"
So you guys recommend me to just make a normal page without any parent, so for example "mywebsite.com/create"

Comment: I am not adding the create page into a sub menu, it's actually a button into the "Guides" page, that's why I want to have mywebsite.com/guides/create". But as I understand, I should just go ahead and create a "mywebsite.com/create" page?
Thank you